# Force mails to be in the same conversation in Outlook client

Tags: email, outlook

I have a system that sends out periodic job status emails. It would be great if in Outlook they were grouped by conversation for each instance of the job instead of showing up individually.

How does Outlook decide if things are in the same conversation and is there any simple way via metadata/headers to influence/force that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX MAPI property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583(v=office.15).aspx).

Unfortunately, OOM does not allow to set the ConversationID and ConversationIndex proeprties, so you would need to use MailItem.PorpertyAccessor.SetProperty.